# Parameterized SQL update query doesn't work

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am already stuck for hours and I don't know what to do.
My code doesn't work in updating student records using parameterized SQL query in VB.Net.

```
    Dim result As Integer
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE students SET Student_Name=@name, Address=@address, Contact_No=@contact WHERE ID_Number=@id_number;", conn)
    conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_number", txt_IDNumber.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt_Name.Text.ToString)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txt_Address.ToString)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", txt_ContactNo.Text.ToString)
    result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If result = 1 Then
        MsgBox("Changes updated successfully.", vbInformation, "Message")
    Else
        MsgBox("Update unsuccessful.", vbCritical, "Message")
    End If
    conn.Close()
```

Comment: Please refer [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx). Also `txt_Address.ToString` should be `txt_Address.Text.ToString`

Comment: @Arulkumar correct, but it depends ultimately on the underlying driver. Access, for example accepts the syntax with the @

Comment: Oops..I didn't see that. Thanks for the quick observation mate. It helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OleDb doesn't recognize parameters by their name. In OleDb parameters should be added to the parameters collection in the same order in which you have listed them in the commandtext.

This means that your code tries to update a record whose *ID_Number* is equal to the content of the *txt_ContactNo*

Just move the parameter *@id_number* after adding the first three

```
' No need to use ToString on a property of type string'
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt_Name.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txt_Address.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", txt_ContactNo.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_number", txt_IDNumber.Text)
```

As a side note, please be aware of [the problems of AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). It is an handy shortcut but you could pay a price for it

Comment: Wow! It works!..That was fast. Well, Honestly I didn't know that in order to work, it should be in the same order as what I have listed in the CommandText. Thank you very much for your time and help. Cheers!